# DWG reprojecton

Tags: coordinate-system, autocad

I`ve tried to reproject a DWG file from NAD83CSRS/17N to WGS84/Latlong as follows

1. Create a new DWG
2. Assigning the target coordinate system to the new DWG
3. Attach original drawing
4. Query all objects from attached DWG
5. Detach DWG
6. Save new DWG
7. Open new DWG and check coordinates.

However when I check the coordinates are still in NAD83CSRS/17N.

Obs? The same issue happen in AutoCAD Map3D and Civil3D, both 2016 and 2017 versions.

Does anyone know what it could be?